# Is it safe to use MainActivity.this

Tags: android

Is it safe to use `MainActivity.this` in anonymous class when starting a new `Activity`, please check the code below. I used to create an init a variable of `Activity` type, but this approach looks better for me.

The question is, is it **safe** to use it?

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SomeOtherActivity.class));
    }
});
```

Comment: What coud be unsafe about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of-course it is safe as you can see this in API demos and sample code. it works fine I never encounter any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the standard approach to refer to the current activity instance from within an inner class.