# How to go back to Sign In activity Firebase authlistener?

Tags: java, android, authentication, firebase

My main/startup activity is my SignInActivity and I've included the 
Firebase auth listener

```
    mFirebase.addAuthStateListener(new Firebase.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(AuthData authData) {
            if (authData != null) {
                // go to auth activity
                // such as user logging in
            } else {
                if(!(this instanceof SignInActivity)){
                    // if i sign out in an auth activity
                    // i want to trigger this to go back to the SignIn Activity
                    Intent mIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SignInActivity.class);
                    mIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(mIntent);
                    finish();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

In the else statement, the if condition does not work. I know I can't use `this` inside a nested object. I've tried a few other attempts but I always get flickering and I think it ends up in a infinite loop because the condition is always met. Whats the right way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mFirebase.addAuthStateListener(new Firebase.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(AuthData authData) {
        if (authData != null) {
            // go to auth activity
            // such as user logging in
        } else {
            if(!(SignInActivity.this instanceof SignInActivity)){
                // if i sign out in an auth activity
                // i want to trigger this to go back to the SignIn Activity
                Intent mIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SignInActivity.class);
                mIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(mIntent);
                finish();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

[Is it safe to use MainActivity.this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14518989/is-it-safe-to-use-mainactivity-this)

Comment: Would that cause mActivity to always be an instance of SignInActivity since its declared in the SignInActivity?

Comment: If the idea here is just to check if a user is logged in when the user reopens the app, you don't need that else statement.  You can just not do anything if the user is not logged in.

Comment: That is one of the reasons. I want this to trigger if the user is inside another activity and the user signs out. When the sign out button/link is clicked then ill unAuth the user and i'm hoping this catches that case and redirects to the SignInActivity